# How to implement the Cortana Speech API or Bing Search API’s in QnA Maker Service?

Tags: api, bots, botframework, cortana-intelligence, bing-search

I am working on Bot technology, in my current bot project I implemented the QnA Maker service with specified questions and answers, till now everything working fine like whenever I asked the question available in my file then immediately bot gives answer to me.

I have followed the below link to implement the QnA Maker

https://qnamaker.ai/Documentation

If question is not there in the file it gives the response like “No Good Match Found in KB(File)”. But I want the functionality like whenever I asked the question not available in the KB file it call Cortana Speech API or Bing Search API for getting the related response of that question.

Can you please tell me how to implement the Cortana Speech API or Bing Search API’s in QnA Maker Service?

Is it possible now, if it is possible Please show me some examples here.

-Pradeep

Comment: The QnA maker is very limited and does not allow extension.

Comment: Above comment is incorrect.  QnA maker simply exposes an endpoint.  If you build a bot with the BotBuilder you can call this endpoint and add any additional functionality you desire.  (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder)